# Where session's are stored in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis, session

By default when a user opens a website he is assigned a unique session that remains intact with him while he is surfing the site. I remember in apache this session is stored as text file on server.

Can any one let me know how autogenerated seesion are stored in IIS and the path where i can see all the seesions of existing users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit :
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0a39701c-77b1-4102-97cb-d5910a05f431.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: This is an article about ASP.NET sessions, he's asking about IIS sessions; and yes, there's a difference between these two.

Answer (score 1):

> You can view/manage sessions in [IIS Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b0c14479-83e3-435d-a935-819fe396e7d2.mspx?mfr=true)
>   or by using the Rsess.vbs command-line
>   script. To manage sessions in IIS
>   Manager, right-click the session, and
>   then click the appropriate action.

Reference - [Managing Sessions (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0a39701c-77b1-4102-97cb-d5910a05f431.mspx?mfr=true)